# Target existing api gateway RestApi using cdk

Tags: c#, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am creating a new event bus and a rule where I need to target one of the existing apigateway rest api as target to the event rule. Here is the code snippet I have done. But this is throwing an error.

> Unable to cast object of type '_Proxy' to type
> 'Amazon.CDK.AWS.APIGateway.RestApi'

```
var restApi = (RestApi)Amazon.CDK.AWS.APIGateway.RestApi.FromRestApiId(this, ApiId, RestApiId); 

var eventBus = new EventBus(this, busName, new EventBusProps
            {
                EventBusName = busName
            });            
            var eventRule = new Rule(this, eventRule, new RuleProps
            {
                EventBus = eventBus,
                RuleName = eventRule,
                Description = "",
                EventPattern = new EventPattern
                {
                    status = new string[] { "somestatus" }
                }                
            });

eventRule.AddTarget(new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.ApiGateway(restApi, new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.ApiGatewayProps
            {
                PostBody = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(inputTransformObj),
                EventRole = role,
                Stage = "prod",
                Method = "POST"
            }));
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Line 1?

Comment: @gshpychka yes Line 1

Comment: Check the method signature, you're casting it to an incompatible type. That methods returns `IRestApi`, not `RestApi`.

Comment: @gshpychka I was trying to cast to RestApi to make it as a target, couldn't see a  way to add IRestAPi as a target to the event rule. Is there any way I can target an existing apigateway as target? Am I doing something wrong at this line "eventRule.AddTarget(new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.ApiGateway(restApi, new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Events.Targets.ApiGatewayProps" ?

Comment: @fedonev so what would be the best way I can target an existing apigateway, I mean look up for an existing apigateway and add as a target to the rule?

Comment: Casting won't help.  This is a known issue: [API Gateway target should accept IRestApi and not RestApi](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CDK [ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events_targets.ApiGateway.html) event target currently requires a `RestApi` type, not the read-only `IRestApi` type returned when importing. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16423). Until the interface is loosened, wire up the target manually. Here's how in Typescript, hopefully it's easy for you to translate to .NET:

Get a reference to the existing API and define the ARN for the endpoint you want the event to hit:

```js
const importedApi = apigw.RestApi.fromRestApiId( this, 'ImportedApi', 'abc3mxg14e' );
const apiArn = importedApi.arnForExecuteApi('GET', '/*/test', 'prod');
```

Create a role permitting EventBridge to call your Api:

```js
const role = new iam.Role(this, 'CallImportedApiRole', {
  assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com'),
  inlinePolicies: {
    CallApi: new iam.PolicyDocument({
      statements: [
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
          actions: ['execute-api:Invoke', 'execute-api:ManageConnections'],
          resources: [apiArn],
        }),
      ],
    }),
  },
});
```

Use the L1 `CfnRule` construct to build the rule. The [HttpParametersProperty](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.CfnRule.HttpParametersProperty.html) defines the endpoint target config:

```js
new events.CfnRule(this, 'InvokeApiRule', {
  scheduleExpression: events.Schedule.rate(cdk.Duration.minutes(10)).expressionString,
  roleArn: role.roleArn,
  state: 'ENABLED',
  targets: [
    {
      arn: apiArn,
      id: 'Target0',
      httpParameters: {
        pathParameterValues: ['presidents'],
        queryStringParameters: { name: 'Zaphod',},
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

#### Note for Typescript CDK users:

Typescript CDK users can skip the above. Casting `importedApi` to `RestApi` will work:

```js
rule.addTarget(
  new targets.ApiGateway(importedApi as apigw.RestApi, {
    method: 'GET',
    stage: 'prod',
    path: '/*/casted',
    pathParameterValues: ['presidents'],
  })
);
```